# How to grep multiple lines from a file in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, administrator, bash-scripting

I have a file with the below content.

```
.
.
hello
.
.
.
world
.
.
hello
.
.
.
.
.
world
.
.
```

the dots indicates the other lines in the file. Here what I need to gerp only the lines hello and world. That means the output should something like below.

```
hello
world
hello
world
```

How to accomplish this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -E 'hello|world' file
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/hello|world/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` with the `-x` option to match whole line and (Extended) Regex operator, `|`, to perform a logical OR between patterns:

```
grep -xE 'hello|world' file.txt
```

If your `grep` doesn't support the `-E` option, use Basic Regex with escaped `|`:

```
grep -x 'hello\|world' file.txt
```

---

Additionally, if you can't use the `-x` option to match the whole line, use Regex operators:

```
grep -E '^(hello|world)$' file.txt
```